# What's the normal way to say you're present during a headcount?

Tags: phrase-requests

I always thought just plain "present" was proper, but apparently my Filipino teacher prefers "I'm here" which sounds really odd. What's the normal way to say you're present during a headcount, especially in a class?

Comment: "*Present*" is fine if a bit formal. Just plain "*Here!*" [with a raise of your hand] is sufficient.

Comment: In schools (in the UK) it's usually _Yes Sir/Miss_ while in most other situations, _Here!_ or _Yes!_ would suffice.